# Solution for a wave equation containing a function

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following PDE:

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\left(\frac{1}{1+0.25\sin\frac{2\pi x}{\varepsilon}}\right)^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)=e^{-t}$$

with $x\in[0,1], t\geq0$ and the following boundary conditions: $u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$, and the initial conditions $u(x,0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial u(x,0)}{\partial t}=0$, where I plan to give at least 4 different values of $\varepsilon$.

Following a book, I have an estimate for the solution, however, when computing it in Mathematica for t=10, it takes a long time for it to finish, and the result makes no sense.

I am a complete newbie to Mathematica, so my question would be if there is a way to compute the solution within Mathematica itself, where I can compare the plots of different values of $\varepsilon$?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide your code  so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pde = D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] -D[(1/(1 + 0.25*Sin[2*Pi*x/epsilon]))^2*D[u[t, x], x], x] - Exp[-t]
bc1 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, x == 0];
bc2 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, x == 1];
ic1 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, t == 0];
ic2 = NeumannValue[0, t == 0];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{pde ==ic2,  ic1 , bc1, bc2}, 
   u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, {epsilon}];

Plot3D[Evaluate@Table[sol[epsilon][t, x], {epsilon, {2, 3}}], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 
  0, 1}, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u[t,x]"}]

Plot[(sol[#][10, x]) & /@ {2, 3} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to see a 2D graphic for a set t (such as t=10)? I am assuming this way it plots 2 different values of epsilon, or is it a range going from 0.5 to 5? Also, isn't there a ^2 missing from the function or was it absorbed somewhere in the code?

Basically, I'm trying to compare the plots given by this problem with the one given by this other one, but I'm having a little trouble making it work as well...

eqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + Exp[-t]
ic = {u[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0}
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0}

Comment: Excuse me for the mess above, I'm not familiar on how to paste code from Mathematica unto this page.

Comment: The plot is completely empty?

Comment: I have no idea why, but when I put your code on Mathematica the plot is completely blank.

Comment: @REVB restart your kernel by go to `Evaluation>Quit Kernel>Local` and then evaluate again.

Comment: I have restarted the kernel, closed and openen Mathematica again and restarted my computer. For some reason, the plot is still blank.

Comment: I'll keep trying tomorrow morning. Thank you so much for your help @zhk, you're a real lifesaver. For further clarification, the 3D plot shows fine, but the 2D one is blank.

Comment: @REVB I have no clue whats wrong on your side. :(

Comment: I GOT IT. You defined t between 0 and 1 when asking the solution, but then asked a value outside that range when doing the plot. I extended the interval for t between 0 and 5, asked for solutions at 5 and got plots :)
https://imgur.com/fNIZC40